# Hide TableView section depending on segue identifier. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tableview

I have a storyboard with two buttons, each one with target to another storyboard with a TableView but different segue identifier.

Right now I populate my data source through a two dimension array

```
var dataArray = [["a", "b", "c"], ["menu 1", "menu 2", "menu 3"]]
```

### **What I would like to do is based on the button selection hide a TableView section.**

**Example:**

Selected button 1 hide section 2 on my TableView.
&
Selected button 2 hide section 1 on my TableView.

My data source extension looks like this

```
extension ViewControllerTwo: UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        
        if section == 0{
            
            return "Section 1"
            
        }
        
        return "Section 2"
            
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        
        if section == 0{
            
            return "Number of items in section 1 is \(dataArray[0].count)"
            
        }
        
        return "Number of items in section 2 is \(dataArray[1].count)"
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return dataArray[section].count
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "singleCell")
        
        if cell == nil{
            
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "singleCell")
            cell?.accessoryType = .detailButton
            
        }
        
        cell!.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            return cell!
        
    }
    
}
```

The two viewControllers are named as follow

- "ViewController"
- "ViewControllerTwo"

Think of the segues identifiers named as follow

- "segueItemsOption" for button 1
- "segueMenuOption" for button 2

### Edit

View Controller Code.

Haven't really modified anything as segue automatically displays the next VC.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: Outlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var itemsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Buttons Rounded Corner
        
        itemsButton.round()
        itemsButton.round()
        
    }

// MARK: Button Actions

@IBAction func itesmButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        
        createVolumes.shine()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func menuButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        
        listVolumes.shine()
        
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code for `ViewController`.

Comment: Done! It's on main question now.

Comment: This is not the complete `ViewController`, is it? So I have to ask direct. What do the methods `createVolumes.shine()` and `listVolumes.shine()` do? Is your data passed down to your `ViewControllerTwo` or is it instantiated there? How is `ViewControllerTwo` instantiated and presented?

Comment: Property `.shine()` is only an UIButtonExtension I created with no real purpose for another ViewController not related to my original query. `ViewControllerTwo` is instantiated through the segue created for each button (show segue). All the information will be obtained directly in `ViewControllerTwo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want you can try following:

Create an enum:

```
enum ShowCase: Int{
    case items, menu
    
    var headerTitle: String{
        switch self {
        case .items:
            return "Section 1"
        case .menu:
            return "Section 2"
        }
    }
    
    static func createFromSegueIdentifier(_ str: String) -> ShowCase{
        str == "segueItemsOption" ? .items : .menu
    }
}
```

In you ViewController add:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    guard let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerTwo, let identifier = segue.identifier else{
        return
    }
    
    vc.showCase = ShowCase.createFromSegueIdentifier(identifier)
    
}
```

in ViewcontrollerTwo add an implicitly unwrapped var:

```
var showCase: ShowCase!
```

and the extension should look like:

```
extension ViewControllerTwo: UITableViewDataSource{
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return only one section
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        showCase.headerTitle
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        "Number of items in \(showCase.headerTitle.lowercased()) is \(dataArray[showCase.rawValue].count)"
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray[showCase.rawValue].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "singleCell")
        
        if cell == nil{
            
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "singleCell")
            cell?.accessoryType = .detailButton
            
        }
        
        cell!.textLabel?.text = dataArray[showCase.rawValue][indexPath.row]
        return cell!
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I believe this might work, will try and let you know!
Got one question, the enum is placed on `ViewController` or `ViewControllerTwo`?

Comment: a@EmilioCG The enum should be placed in its own file. As it needs to be accessible in both controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, try creating an if condition for each segue and .isHidden property.
That works 100% fam

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).